# Access userControl inside formView footer template from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, devexpress, formview

I have the following code:

```
   <asp:FormView runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>

            <div>
                <hr/>
                <uc1:Footer runat="server" ID="Footer" />
            </div>

        </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
```

In Footer.ascx I have:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="lbl" runat="server" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="10px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

I want to access my user control FooterDetail from the code behind to set lbl value.

How can'I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to provide a property that returns the `Label` of the `UserControl` or better just it's `Text`. Then you can use the `FormView`'s [`FooterRow` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.footerrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `FindControl` to get it:

```
var uc = (UserControlTypeName)FormView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Footer");
uc.Value = "New Value";
```

Here's the property in your `UserControl`:

```
public string Value
{
    get { return lbl.Text; }
    set { lbl.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but for me FormView1.FooterRow is null

Comment: @Nabila: is `FooterRow` or `FooterRow.FindControl("Footer")` null? In general this property is set in/after `FormView.ItemCreated`. So if you try to access it earlier (f.e. from `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`) it is null. The solution is to access it later (f.e. in `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound` of the `FormView` or `PreRender` of the `Page`).